# Seeking Advice on Designing a Clean Data Class (Model) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, model, architecture, clean-architecture, data-class

I'm currently working on designing a neat data class (model) for an AlarmTime instance, which will play the role of a variable in the Alarm class. I've come up with two solutions, and I'd love some advice on figuring out which one vibes better with Kotlin conventions and is just generally a good fit for this situation. If these two ideas are way off base, I'd be super grateful for any examples or guidance you could share.

Thanks a bunch!

#### Solution1

```
data class AlarmTime private constructor(
    val hour: Int,
    val minute: Int,
) {
    fun toCombinedMinutes(): Int = hour * 60 + minute

    companion object {
        private const val MAX_COMBINED_MINUTES = 1439 // 23 * 60 + 59

        operator fun invoke(hour: Int, minute: Int) =
            when {
                hour >= 24 || hour < 0 -> throw IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid hour value. Hour must be within the range of 0 to 23.")
                minute >= 60 || minute < 0 -> throw IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid minute value. Minute must be within the range of 0 to 59.")
                else -> AlarmTime(hour, minute)
            }

        operator fun invoke(combinedMinutes: Int) =
            when {
                combinedMinutes > MAX_COMBINED_MINUTES || combinedMinutes < 0 ->
                    throw IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Invalid combined minutes value. " +
                                "Combined minutes must be within the range of 0 to 1439"
                    )
                else -> AlarmTime(
                    hour = combinedMinutes / 60,
                    minute =  combinedMinutes % 60
                )
            }
    }
}
```

#### Solution2

```
data class Hour private constructor (val value: Int) {

    companion object {
       operator fun invoke(hour: Int) =
           when {
               hour >= 24 || hour < 0 -> throw IllegalArgumentException(
                   "Invalid hour value. Hour must be within the range of 0 to 23."
               )
               else -> Hour(hour)
           }
    }
}

data class Minute private constructor(val value: Int) {

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(minute: Int) =
            when {
                minute >= 60 || minute < 0 -> throw IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid minute value. Minute must be within the range of 0 to 59."
                )
                else -> Minute(minute)
            }
    }
}

data class CombinedMinutes(val value: Int) {

    fun getHour(): Hour = Hour(this.value / 60)
    fun getMinute(): Minute = Minute(this.value % 60)

    companion object {
        private const val MAX_COMBINED_MINUTES = 1439 // 23 * 60 + 59

        operator fun invoke(combinedMinutes: Int) =
            when {
                combinedMinutes > MAX_COMBINED_MINUTES || combinedMinutes < 0 ->
                    throw IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Invalid combined minutes value. " +
                                "Combined minutes must be within the range of 0 to 1439"
                    )
                else -> CombinedMinutes(combinedMinutes)
            }

        operator fun invoke(hour: Hour, minute: Minute) =
            CombinedMinutes(hour.value * 60 + minute.value)
    }
}

data class AlamTime2 private constructor(val hour: Hour, val minute: Minute) {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(hour: Hour, minute: Minute) =
            AlamTime2(hour, minute)

        operator fun invoke(combinedMinutes: CombinedMinutes) =
            AlamTime2(combinedMinutes.getHour(), combinedMinutes.getMinute())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to challenge your premise that a data class is a good fit for what you intend to do.

While not stated explicitly, from your code it looks like that you want to make sure that invalid `AlarmTime` can't be created.
This will not work with data classes because one of the things you get for free is the [copy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) function which enforces the types of values but not the validation. In particular the following compiles and runs:

```
AlarmTime(12,30).copy(minute = -1)
  .also { println(it) } // AlarmTime(hour=12, minute=-1)
```

This is an issue with Solution 1 and even more so with Solution 2 - consider this example that sets minutes to -1:

```
AlamTime2(Hour(12), Minute(30))
  .copy(minute = Minute(1).copy(value = -1) )
```

Without specific additional requirements (e.g equals/hashcode), I'd go for the simplified variant of Solution 1

```
class AlarmTime(val hour: Int, val minute: Int) {

    constructor(combinedMinutes: Int) : this(
        hour = combinedMinutes / 60,
        minute = combinedMinutes % 60
    )
    
    init {
        require(hour in 0..23) {
            "Invalid hour value: $hour. Hour must be within the range [0 .. 23]"
        }
        require(minute in 0..59) {
            "Invalid minute value: $minute. Minute must be within the range [0 .. 59]."
        }
    }

    override fun toString(): String = "AlarmTime(hour=$hour, minute=$minute)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate your clarification. Indeed, as you pointed out, with Solution1, it's possible to set a -1 minutes value. However, when using Solution2, attempting to set the minute to -1 results in an exception. Here's an example:


try {
    AlarmTime(Hour(12), Minute(30)).copy(minute = Minute(-1))
        .also { println(it) }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println(e.message)
}

What are your thoughts on this approach?

Comment: That just pushes the problem one level lower: `AlamTime2(Hour(12), Minute(30)).copy(minute = Minute(1).copy(value = -1) )`

Comment: Ah, thanks for getting back so quickly! I get that it not catch illegal statements. I'll stick with your cleaned-up code. Big thanks! If you've got any other cool solutions or links, hit me up. Really appreciate your help!